# Azure ARM template - run powershell script against VMs located in many different az regions

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I have prepared ARM template for Windows VMs configuration. Code presented below. I tested this ARM template agains list of VMs located in the same region, and it worked as expected, deployment completed successfully. Problem is when I would like to run that code against VMs located in many az regions, is there any way to do it?

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vmName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "List of virtual machines to be reconfigured, if using multiple VMs, make their names comma separate. E.g. VM01, VM02, VM03."
            },
            "defaultValue": "VM1,VM2"
        },
        "Location": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location of the VM"
            },
            "defaultvalue": "WestEurope"
        },
        "customScriptFileToRun": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify the name of the configuration script"
            },
            "defaultvalue": "script.ps1"
        },
        "secureFileUri": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "xxxxxxx",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Secure SAS blob URL"
            }
        },
        "OMSWorkspaceResourceGroup": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Log analytics workspace Resource Group"
            },
            "defaultvalue": "yourLogAnalyticsRG"
        },
        "omsWorkspacename": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Log analytics workspace name"
            },
            "defaultvalue": "YourLoganalyticsworkspacename"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "vmListArray": "[split(parameters('vmName'),',')]",
        "commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File', ' ', parameters('customScriptFileToRun'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
            "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
            "name": "[concat(trim(variables('vmListArray')[copyIndex()]),'/WindowsRegModyfication')]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "ExtentionLooptoAllVMs",
                "count": "[length(variables('vmListArray'))]"
            },
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "properties": {
                "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                "settings": {
                    "fileUris": [
                        "[parameters('secureFileUri')]"
                    ],
                    "commandToExecute": "[variables('commandToExecute')]"
                },
                "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
                "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
                "typeHandlerVersion": "1.8",
                "protectedSettings": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: whats the issue? create an array of regions for those vms and access those?

Comment: Can You extend yous suggestion, its not clear form me. You mean array of regions, and array of VMs, how can I associate both arrays in ARM? I need specific region for a VM, one VM will be in easteurope, second in northeurope etc...

Comment: well, thats up to you, but you need to map vm to a region and use that data in your arm template to dynamically define a region, instead of hardcoding it

Comment: ok, I have to go through MS documentation, at this moment dont know hot to create such mapping VM <--> az region

Comment: Hi @4c74356b41, can You give me some explanation how can i resolve my issue? I know that in case of Resourcegroup we can use  resourcegroup().location, resourcegroup().id, resourcegroup().name. But How can I create this mapping in case of VM and the region? It should be useful something like VM().location...

Comment: With Azure arm template function, we cannot get azure VM name and region. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource. So I think we need to provide these value for arm template by ourselvs.

Comment: Hi, @Jim Xu, so you are saying that in my scenario, where I want to run my ARM extension script against list of VMs (located in a different regions) there is no way to do this? and only way is to prepare separete ARMs for a specific region, one ARM for VMs in easteurope, second ARM fo VMs in northeurope etc...?

Answer (score 0):

According to your need, we can define vmName and location as the parameter in Azure ARm template and use PowerShell `get-AzVm` to list all windows VM.

For example

My template.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vmName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "List of virtual machines to be reconfigured, if using multiple VMs, make their names comma separate. E.g. VM01, VM02, VM03."
            }
        },
        "Location": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location of the VM"
            }
        },
        "customScriptFileToRun": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify the name of the configuration script"
            },
            "defaultvalue": "installWebServer.ps1"
        },
        "secureFileUri": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-docs-json-samples/master/tutorial-vm-extension/installWebServer.ps1",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "the file URL"
            }
        }

    },
    "variables": {

        "commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File', ' ', parameters('customScriptFileToRun'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {

             "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",

            "properties": {


            }

        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
            "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
            "name": "[concat( parameters('vmName'),'/WindowsRegModyfication')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('vmName'))]"
            ],
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "properties": {
                "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                "settings": {
                    "fileUris": [
                        "[parameters('secureFileUri')]"
                    ],
                    "commandToExecute": "[variables('commandToExecute')]"
                },
                "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
                "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
                "typeHandlerVersion": "1.8",
                "protectedSettings": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

2. deploy

```
$vms=Get-AzVM | Where-Object {$_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType -eq 'Windows'}
foreach($vm in $vms){

   $TemplateObject=@{"vmName"=$vm.Name;"Location"=$vm.Location}

  New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -TemplateFile "E:\template.json" -TemplateParameterObject $TemplateObject -Debug

}
```

Comment: Hi Jim, Your solution works, I've tested it, but this parameter ` -Debug` force user do confirm many questions during the deployment. I tried to remove ` -Debug`, but it this case ARM template doesn't work as expected, there is no changes on the VMs. Is there any way to avoid clicking all these massages caused by ` -Debug`.??